# How to run commands inside a docker container from another docker container that runs a flask server?

Tags: python, linux, docker, flask

Sorry to not post any codes because work won't allow me since it is a confidential code.

My problem is that I have a docker compose file that runs 2 dockers. one (admin container) that has `script.sh` and the other one has a flask server and the only thing common between them is that they share the same volume. what i try to do is at some point when the flask server gets a "POST" request to some functions ,that `script.sh` needs to be executed in the other container.
I tried `os.system("./script.sh")`and that will of course try to run it in the wrong container. i tried also to run stuff through `docker exec` and that did not work because the flask container can't see the other running container so i can do that only from the outside system. i also cannot run any listener in the admin container because it has a python socket running on it.

Any solution please ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can't do this; each container has its own isolated filesystem space, and one container can't see another's files or run programs there.  Why can't you set up a network listener or an HTTP interface?

Comment: @DavidMaze this is my first time working with containers. what i thought is when for example a server or a listener is running under a port in some container means you can't run another one in the same container because it uses one only port. but looks like it is not . so i will try to run a python socket inside that admin container and see if it works. and thank you for you comment